# difference betwen who and finger command in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Both commands look like have same purpose but their output is different. what is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

1. `finger`, when pointed at a specific user, can display detailed information (shell, homedir, last login time, mailbox status, `~/.plan`)
2. `finger` can also be used over the network: [`finger @athena.dialup.mit.edu`](http://nullroute.eu.org/finger/?q=%40athena.dialup.mit.edu)
3. Because of #2, `finger` is also sometimes used for simplistic database queries: [`finger john@db.debian.org`](http://nullroute.eu.org/finger/?q=john%40db.debian.org), [`finger help_general@mit.edu`](http://nullroute.eu.org/finger/?q=help_general%40mit.edu), [`finger @bathroom.mit.edu`](http://nullroute.eu.org/finger/?q=%40bathroom.mit.edu)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ man finger

NAME
  finger — user information lookup program

$ man who

NAME
   who - show who is logged on
```

Comment: Always check the man pages.

Answer (score 2):

`who` tells you very basic information about what users are logged on.  `finger` tells you personal information about a user, possibly including real name, office location, and office phone number.  Obviously finger is less used now, for various reasons including privacy.

Note that finger has a long-form option, `-l`, that provides additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Finger was a way to get information about a user from another system. You could do a 
finger gandalf@example.com
and see my full name, phone number, where I connect from, and a short message from me.

Who is used when you are on a machine to see who else is on the machine.