# how do I display the current users who logged into the system more than once?

Tags: unix

So far I can list the names of the users who logged in. However, how can I display the users logged in more than once?

```
finger | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sort -u` use just `sort` and then [`uniq -d`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html).

> `-d`
> Suppress the writing of lines that are not repeated in the input.

Consider using `who` instead of `finger` because:

- `finger` may display a header* (it does in my Kubuntu);
- `finger` is not required by POSIX, [`who`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/who.html) is;
- [the purpose of `finger` is broader](https://superuser.com/q/133987/432690).

**The whole command:**

```
who | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq -d
```

I think all these tools and options are required by POSIX. The command is thus portable.

---

<sup>* You can start with `finger` if you really want. In most cases the header will not make any difference because its first field will appear only once. In my OS the first field in the header is `Login`. If there was a user named `Login` then the header would cause a bug. So it's better to filter out the header anyway (`tail -n +2`). There is no such problem with `who`.</sup>